# change jQuery code to open modal on load and use button

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, onload

I would Like the code to open the modal on load and using the button. Is this possible? 
Or will I need to use two different scripts? In a perfect world the script would include a cookie so the on load modal would not continue to open on frequent visitors/

updated code I wanted to use below.

```
;( function( window ) {

'use strict';

var transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function extend( a, b ) {
    for( var key in b ) { 
        if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            a[key] = b[key];
        }
    }
    return a;
}

function UIMorphingButton( el, options ) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
    extend( this.options, options );
    this._init();
}

UIMorphingButton.prototype.options = {
    closeEl : '',
    onBeforeOpen : function() { return false; },
    onAfterOpen : function() { return false; },
    onBeforeClose : function() { return false; },
    onAfterClose : function() { return false; }
}

UIMorphingButton.prototype._init = function() {
    // the button
    this.button = this.el.querySelector( 'button' );
    // state
    this.expanded = false;
    // content el
    this.contentEl = this.el.querySelector( '.morph-content' );
    // init events
    this._initEvents();
}

UIMorphingButton.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    // open
    this.button.addEventListener( 'click', function() { self.toggle(); } );
    // close
    if( this.options.closeEl !== '' ) {
        var closeEl = this.el.querySelector( this.options.closeEl );
        if( closeEl ) {
            closeEl.addEventListener( 'click', function() { self.toggle(); } );
        }
    }
}

UIMorphingButton.prototype.toggle = function() {
    if( this.isAnimating ) return false;

    // callback
    if( this.expanded ) {
        this.options.onBeforeClose();
    }
    else {
        // add class active (solves z-index problem when more than one button is in the page)
        classie.addClass( this.el, 'active' );
        this.options.onBeforeOpen();
    }

    this.isAnimating = true;

    var self = this,
        onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( ev.target !== this ) return false;

            if( support.transitions ) {
                // open: first opacity then width/height/left/top
                // close: first width/height/left/top then opacity
                if( self.expanded && ev.propertyName !== 'opacity' || !self.expanded && ev.propertyName !== 'width' && ev.propertyName !== 'height' && ev.propertyName !== 'left' && ev.propertyName !== 'top' ) {
                    return false;
                }
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            self.isAnimating = false;

            // callback
            if( self.expanded ) {
                // remove class active (after closing)
                classie.removeClass( self.el, 'active' );
                self.options.onAfterClose();
            }
            else {
                self.options.onAfterOpen();
            }

            self.expanded = !self.expanded;
        };

    if( support.transitions ) {
        this.contentEl.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
    }
    else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
    }

    // set the left and top values of the contentEl (same like the button)
    var buttonPos = this.button.getBoundingClientRect();
    // need to reset
    classie.addClass( this.contentEl, 'no-transition' );
    this.contentEl.style.left = 'auto';
    this.contentEl.style.top = 'auto';

    // add/remove class "open" to the button wraper
    setTimeout( function() { 
        self.contentEl.style.left = buttonPos.left + 'px';
        self.contentEl.style.top = buttonPos.top + 'px';

        if( self.expanded ) {
            classie.removeClass( self.contentEl, 'no-transition' );
            classie.removeClass( self.el, 'open' );
        }
        else {
            setTimeout( function() { 
                classie.removeClass( self.contentEl, 'no-transition' );
                classie.addClass( self.el, 'open' ); 
            }, 25 );
        }
    }, 25 );
}

// add to global namespace
window.UIMorphingButton = UIMorphingButton;
```

})( window );

Answer (score 0):

do something like

```
//show modal on button click
$(document).on('click', '#myButtonId', function(){
    $('#myModalId').dialog();
});
```

then add this:

```
// trigger the button being clicked on window load
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myButtonId').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: The way you have it it looks simple, but working it into the code I added above is a maze I can't tackle. :/